# RavenDb connectionstring memory=true not working

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, ravendb

I'm trying to setup unit tests for a Web Api app with RavenDb.Client. The app is using a RavenDb server running as a service and works just fine.

In my test project I've set the connection string to Memory=True, but the tests throws an exception saying that "memory" is an unknown option.

What am I doing wrong?

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="RavenDbConnectionString" connectionString="memory=1"/>
  </connectionStrings>


IDocumentStore store = new DocumentStore()
            {
                ConnectionStringName = "RavenDbConnectionString"
            }.Initialize();
```

Answer (score 3):

memory=1 is not the same as memory=true.

Comment: That's true, but I get the same error regardless if I use memory=1 or memory=true.

Comment: Yes, you are using _document store_, you need to use _embeddable document store_